# Scala Akka actor, validation of messages

Tags: validation, scala, akka

This is an Architecture/design form question as I have a nominally workable solution.  I want to see if there is a better way...

I have an actor which handles a number of messages.  Each message may have its own content structure validation.  I wish to know if there is a suitable pattern for (near seemless) message validation.  For example, if I did

```
val f:Future[Any] = actorRef ask MyMessage(invalidContent)
```

I could expect back:

```
f = Future.failure(ValidationException(someMessage))
```

Currently I have achieved this by creating a wrapper which inherits

```
trait ValidatingActorRef[-T] {

  def actorRef:ActorRef

  def validate:PartialFunction[T, Option[ValidationException]]

  def ask(message:T)(implicit timeout:Timeout):Future[Any] =
    validate
      .lift(message)
      .flatten
      .map(t => Future.failed(t))
      .getOrElse(akka.pattern.ask(actorRef, message))
}
```

Giving me

```
val myActorRefWrapper = new ValidatingActorRef[MyMessages] {  

  val actorRef = system.system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])

  val log = {

    case MyMessage(content) if content == badContent =>
      BadContentValidationException("you have bad content")
  }
```

}

What I have got here is a validation response without having to waste time on the actor mailbox, or dealing with a future.  However the wrapper approach isnt very seemless, I have explicitly wire in a ValidatingActorRef, not just an ActorRef

Is there a better pattern?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you talking about testing or are you talking about something else? I feel your question is more about your solution than the problem itself.

Comment: I was using it to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve but I'm not happy with my solution.  Im thinking in terms of separation, primarily for testing but also context and reusing.  For example I could use the same actor to process writing a document to disk, but different validators for checking the document contents

Comment: By 'use the same actor', I mean the same implementation, not the same ref

Comment: Personally I don't think validation should be conflated with exceptions. Exceptions should be reserved for failures.

Comment: I was thinking of looking into the Scalaz validation trait.  How would you handle authorisation, say changing a property you are not allowed to?  It feels kind of like validation, but also like an exception as this often involved retrieving data and applying some sort of security logic.

Comment: Although I do like having a Future[ResultType] and validation failures going into the failure part, otherwise I need a Future[Validation[,]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is better to validate message not on the sender side, but on actors side.

Just wrap your `receive` method with general validation logic and mixin some validation implementation.

Also check presentation from ooyala guys - http://slideshare.net/EvanChan2/akka-inproductionpnw-scala2013. Look from 14th slide and find how they build stackable traits on actors

Comment: Hmmm, I find I have three message handling components, validate, log and handle.  I could, in theory, abstract all three implementations and mix them in to a generalised actor template, though handler will need to have a reference to sender

Comment: You may check presentation from ooyala guys - http://www.slideshare.net/EvanChan2/akka-inproductionpnw-scala2013. Look from 14th slide and find how they build stackable traits on actors. I have update my answer